# Changing the text color of a navigation bar title when "prefersLargeTitles" is set to true

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationbar, ios11

I have a requirement in which I have to use a `UINavigationBar` with a red large title.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
func prepareNavigationController() {
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
    navController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.red]
}
```

But it's not actually tinting the title label to red. This is the result:

[image: Ignored title color]

But changing `prefersLargeTitles` to false does the right thing, and my title is red.

`navController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`

[image: Tinted Title]

I am not entirely sure if this is a bug since at the time of this writing we are still in the first beta, or if this is intentional behavior, mostly because I haven't any of Apple's apps color the large titles before. Is there any way to actually get the large title to have any color I want?

Comment: I'm searching for the exact same thing! And I didn't find out yet how to change it, maybe since it's the first beta Apple haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: Maybe this could be the right answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46007201/7048642

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is a new UINavigationBar property "largeTitleTextAttribute" that should help with this.

[largeTitleTextAttribute](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2919946-largetitletextattributes)

Here is a sample code you can add to your view controllers viewDidLoad method

```
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
```

[image]

Here is a sample code and screenshot without the largeTitleTextAttributes set, but the barStyle is set to .black

```
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

[image]

Here is a screenshot without the largeTitleTextAttributes set, but the barStyle is set to .default

```
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Is this new to Beta 3? I have yet to download it but I will do so now and check it out.

Comment: Yes new to beta 3. Or at least I noticed it only now.

Comment: I will confirm in a few hours (slow internet), because the symbol doesn't exist on Beta 2.

Comment: I can confirm that the symbol is there on Beta 3. Very interesting find, I will now see if it works. If it does, I will mark your answer as accepted (Provided you add some sample code to help future people who will stumble upon this question).

Answer (score 12):

The way you do this in iOS 13 has changed, you now use `UINavigationBarAppearance` class like this…

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance(idiom: .phone)
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemRed]
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemRed]
appearance.backgroundColor = .white
navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

Comment: Setting the `standardAppearance` property of my `navigationItem` has no effect. In particular, I doing this within `viewWillAppear` of my view controller and using `UINavigationBarAppearance` to set the `largeTitleTextAttributes`. Any thoughts on why this may be the case?

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if it's a bug in beta 1 & 2, but here is a way to set the color. It's a bit of a "hacky" workaround, but it should work until Apple fixes this. In both the Objective-C and Swift version, this code goes in the `viewDidAppear:` method.

Objective-C:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
        NSArray <__kindof UIView *> *subviews = view.subviews;
        if (subviews.count > 0) {
            UILabel *label = subviews[0];
            if (label.class == [UILabel class]) {
                [label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Swift:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     for view in self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews ?? [] {  
     let subviews = view.subviews  
     if subviews.count > 0, let label = subviews[0] as? UILabel {  
           label.textColor = UIColor.red
 } } }
```

Comment: This is actually the only solution that worked for me on iOS 12

Answer (score 2):

If using storyboard, just change "Large Title Text Attributes" Title Color at  Navigation Bar Attribute Inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working code to use large titles and sets the text color of small and large titles to white, both on iOS11+ and on older iOS versions.

```
// Will apply to versions before iOS 11
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
]

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
    ]
}
```

*(There used to be a bug in Xcode, but it now appears to be fixed)*

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 14, Swift 5 and iOS 15 you can change the large title color through the storyboard attribute inspector. The default color is black. You need to select the Navigation Bar, then Attributes Inspector. Go to Scroll Edge Bar Button Appearances section to find the "Prefers Large Titles" checkbox:

[image: Prefers Large Titles]

Then you need to set Large Title to custom and Title color to whatever you want (eg: white) as indicated by the red arrows.

[image: Changing Title Color]