# How to change color for Navigation Bar title?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a simple navigation bar, and title that i set through storyboard. I have set a white color for title.

[image]

Then i have increased the size.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

[image]

This automatically changed the color/font and all properties of my title.

I have tried several ways (as we normally change all attributes), but it looks like non of them work on this after i have increased size.

**How to customize title in this case?**

**Note***: I am asking about color for specific NavVC/VC title. Not in AppDelegate for all VC.

**Answer:** Please follow:
[Changing the text color of a navigation bar title when "prefersLargeTitles" is set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619396/changing-the-text-color-of-a-navigation-bar-title-when-preferslargetitles-is-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Simple thing go to the storyboard select Navigation Bar in Navigation Controller Scene

[image]

Then Set the Colour of Normal Title and Large Title from Attributes inspector like this:

[image]

**Output is:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to do it in Code. Appreciated also.

Comment: @SalehAhmadzada Most Welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code to change the color

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.orange]
```

Try like this if the other one is not working;

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        //To change iOS 11 navigationBar largeTitle color

        UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.white]

    } else {
        // for default navigation bar title color
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.white]

    }
```

Comment: Second one is also not working. Just in case, this is a first page. I have tried to access navBarItem, did not work again. It looks like that line of code in question, block everything.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this code in viewDidLoad() to change the color/font of the title.

```
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes =
                [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green,
                 NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

Comment: Does not work again. That is what i was saying. Already tried almost all i know.